# Change Unity Default Dash Shortcuts

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, customization, shortcuts, default

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 running Unity Desktop and I'd like to change the default shortcuts of the Unity Dash (Super+a for Application, Super+c for Photos, Super+v for Videos, etc.) but can't find the options anywhere.
I already looked in Unity-Tweak-Tool and CompizConfig-Settings-Manager.

Can they be changed?

I really just use the Dash with tapping the Super key and I'd like to assign the other shortcuts to other applications.

There is also a problem with the Super+t shortcut. It opens the trash, though I reassigned it to the terminal in the keyboard settings. 
Also the 'Show Desktop' shortcut is set to Ctrl+Alt+d but still lives on Super+D (They work both at the moment ... )

Seems like it's hardcoded, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Parcial answer: to change some of the shortcuts you mention (Super + a, c, v,...) you need to edit the proper file ending with .scope that you'll find in /usr/share/unity/scopes (you need to be superuser in order to edit these files).

For example, if you want to reassign the shortcut super + a with the compiz manager you first need to find the file: /usr/share/unity/scopes/applications.scope and change the line: "Shortcut=a" by a letter you won't use ("Shortcut=n" for instance).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Should this be followed by a system restart?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer here, but more then a comment.

*If* this is currently possible, I'm guessing it would involve editing the appropriate [`.desktop` files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand), but I can't find such a file for Trash or Desktop, which makes me think the letters for those are hard-coded in to Unity.

Of course you can assign shortcuts under Keyboard settings, but that doesn't work quite the same way.